# Migrate uComponents Related Links datatype data to Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to upgrade from Umbraco 6 to 7, and I used the uComponents Related Links data type in Umbraco 6, so I need to change to use the standard Umbraco 7 Related Links data type instead. The data needs to change from XML to JSON. Does anyone know how to go about doing that?

It'd also be great to trigger something automatically when the upgrade happens - but I can only find mention of GUID -> alias mapping in the upgrade documentation.

Thanks! And I'm amazed I can't find anyone else trying to do this!

Comment: What were the exact versions of Umbraco and uComponents that you are migrating from and to? This is important to form an accurate answer for you.

Comment: v6.2.5 (Assembly version: 1.0.5529.18434) to version 7.2.4 assembly: 1.0.5557.19139